# show input field value in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-input

I have a button, when I click on it a form is shown, It has and input field name, I am trying to display input field value in a another div after submitting the form. But I am unable to do it.
What I am doing wrong?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
        function showDiv() {
            document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "block";
        }
        function showValue(){
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = name;
        }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="showDiv()" value="click on me"/>  
    <form id="hello"  style="display:none;">
        <label>Enter Name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" required>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="showValue()">
    </form>
    <div id="ans"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me, thanks In advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value actually appears in the `div` but your form submits immediately. One way to get away is to not use submit button. Change `input[type=submit]` to `button[type=button]`.

This will prevent the form from being submitted.

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "block";
}

function showValue() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = name;
  document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="showDiv()" value="click on me" />
<form id="hello" style="display:none;">
  <label>Enter Name: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="showValue()">submit</button>
</form>
<div id="ans"></div>
```

Comment: Sir I want to hide the form after submit, only want to show the value of input. how to do this ?

Comment: @JamieSouthwell -- Glad to help. Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: @JamieSouthwell -- please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It will guide you on upvoting/accepting answers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "block";
}

function showValue() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = name;
  document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="showDiv()" value="click on me" />
<form id="hello" style="display:none;">
  <label>Enter Name: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="showValue()">submit</button>
</form>
<div id="ans"></div>
```